# Get data from different tables with Slim2 Framework & Eloquent that are related by an id

Tags: php, orm, twig

I am trying to show a list of items from table B that belongs to categories in table A. I am using Slim 2 with Eloquent as ORM and Twig as `viewtemplate`.

It should look something like this:

```
<ul>    
  {% for item in items %}
    <li>{{ item.id }}</li>
    <li>{{ item.name }}</li>
    <li>{{ item.category }}</li>
  {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Now my category `table(A)` has a primary `ID`. The items `table(B)` has a `category_id` field which corresponds with category ID (table A)

How can I get this to work? Any help is very appreciated

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships

Comment: @MikaTuupola: That doesn't really help me unfortunately. I am so new to framework (Slim). How would it look like in a model, routing and view? Could you explain please?

Comment: Your question is not related to Slim. It is more about how database relationships work with Eloquent.

Comment: @MikaTuupola: Well .. actually it's both. I use Slim 2 with Eloquent and Twig. So I am trying to figure out how to get the data from 2 different tables which are related by an 'id' and then render the outcome in an '<ul>' inside a navbar (dropdown list). As I read some post of you, I thought you would be the right person to ask.